# Required Block Size for XTS Using MSFT CNG

Tags: bcrypt, xts

I am struggling with using Microsoft's BCrypt library in AES-XTS mode.

I've confirmed that the Cipher Block Size is 16 bytes (by getting the BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH property). I'm setting the Data Unit Size to 256 (by setting the key property BCRYPT_MESSAGE_BLOCK_LENGTH); I realize 256 is a bit unconventional, and 512 or 4096 would be more typical, but that's what we need to use for historical reasons.

My problem is this: My call to BcryptEncrypt is failing with "bad parameter" unless I pass in a block that is rounded to a multiple of the Data Unit Size. I don't understand why this would be required.

I would expect, at most, I should need to "round up" to Cipher Block Size.

In my experiments, passing a 512 byte block to BCryptEncrypt works, but a 528 byte block does not.

Is there something I don't understand about XTS? Or something I don't understand about MSFT's implementation?

I'm struggling to understand whether my lack of knowledge is in the implementation details of BCrypt or the implementation details of XTS mode.

Thanks for whatever help you can provide.

Comment: I rather find this completely a library decision, XTS-AES ( key requirements are either 256 or 512) can work on a full block of one or more ( 16-byte) plus partial block (<16-byte). See bottom of page 9 of [NIST 800-38e](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38e.pdf). I guess, it is more about the sector, block size of the disks.

Comment: There are some thoughts, I didn't check this, but it seems to be plausible. Probably you need to pass `BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING` flag to `BCryptEncrypt` (see docs). Moreover, XTS-AES supports padding for one partial block in data unit. Data unit with size of 16 bytes is just a one block (528 bytes consist of two 256-byte data units plus one block). There are too much bytes left up to full data unit.

Comment: @GeorgyFirsov: Thanks for the idea. But, logically, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING tells the algo that you're passing something LESS than a full block... but, as you noted, I'm passing two "data units" plus a full block. And, practically speaking, adding BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING to the call doesn't work.